# Conversion from Equatorial Coordinate to Horizon Coordinates

Tags: star, coordinate

I'm developing my own Planetarium software using C++ following the book [Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet 4th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010WFOATY).

I don't know if I my formulas are correct or not, but when I check my results (Azimuth and Altitude) with Stellarium, they are different.

I have also checked my values with this [page](http://www.stargazing.net/mas/al_az.htm), but they are different. By the way, the azimuth and altitude given in that page are also different from the values given in Stellarium.

Do you know where can I find the formulas to covert celestial coordinate to horizontal coordinates?

Comment: Several immediate thoughts (eg, are you using radians when computing trigonometric functions), but the most obvious question: can we see your source code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using radians. And no, you can't see my source code. There are a lot of classes.

Comment: Did you verified your results other sources, and also cross-checked the same for stellarium?  Maybe your reference frame is different.

Comment: How about just the part of your source code that does the calculation? Trying to debug a "black box" is fairly difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from which celestial coordinates you are converting. I suppose you are working in equatorial coordinates. Then, you can convert as following:

$$\tan A = {\sin h \over \cos h \sin\phi_o - \tan\delta \cos\phi_o} $$ $$ \begin{cases}
 \cos a \sin A = \cos\delta \sin h \\
 \cos a \cos A =  \cos\delta \cos h \sin\phi_o - \sin\delta \cos\phi_o
\end{cases}$$ $$\sin a = \sin\phi_o \sin\delta + \cos\phi_o \cos\delta \cos h$$

Where $A$ is azimuth, $a$ altitude, $\alpha$ right ascension, $\delta$ declination, $h$ hour angle and $\phi_0$ the observer's latitude.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_coordinate_system#Equatorial_.E2.86.90.E2.86.92_horizontal)

Comment: Yes, that is the formula that I am using.